# Reinforcement algorithm for Trading

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement a Reinforcement Learning Algorithm in a trading scenario.
It seems natural to me to use final profit as the reward. However, in this scenario, for each trading episode, there is only one reward, obtained at the end. Is there any RL algorithm that could learn only based on final reward ?
If it was a mario game, how could I train a network only based on a reward earned at the end of the level, but that depends of all previous actions ?

What I'm trying to do is very similar to https://dzone.com/articles/trading-strategies-using-deep-reinforcement-learni

Comment: You'd get better responses to this question if you migrated it to [datascience.se].

Comment: I would have suggested the quant finance stack exchange... people have made money of the stock market way before the apparition of machine learning. However, I am affraid the answer will either be (1) reinforcement learning do not particularly perform well outside of some very specific problems (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3551/optimal-execution-and-reinforcement-learning) or (2) an absence of answer as competent people are probably busy making money of it.

Comment: or (3) this has mostly been answered : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-can-i-go-about-applying-machine-learning-algorithms-to-stock-markets

Comment: Yeah I'm aware it would probably be easier to do without using a single NN, but my interest is both in learning machine learning and in making money. I am pretty sure it's possible to achieve good results with RL, but I'm unsure of my ability do do it by myself... I guess someone that knows about RL but nothing about trading could be of great help, if I have to forget about RL I guess I know how to achieve decent results by myself

Comment: After reading those posts, I feel like it is pretty difficult to apply AI to finance (Sad, just spend 2 days scrapping a good dataset haha)

Comment: It has changed a bit since the posts. most notably thanks to Lopez de Prado, (he has published Advances in Financial Machine Learning) and some people implementing his book (see MLfinLab on github). They provided guidelines on how to better use ML in finance. However, I am yet to see actual results from those techniques.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you would have posted this in quantF SE site the most people there would have argued that it is not possible with machine learning techniques to do trading. - One can verify this because of the thread you linked in your comment. - The underlaing argument they are making have something to do with Efficient Market Hypothesis (Fama 1970) and the CAPM. You can read more about that in the original article or on wikipedia.

The point is that the EMH is a scientific hypothesis, that holds under certain circumstances. Nothing more and less. The research in the past decades proved the hypothesis in several markets and configuration. But the problem - which has been fixed by Fama later - is the size premium and the value premium. Because of this, a lot of people (e.g. Buffett and Graham) relayed on value investing (or fundamental) strategies.

The EMH additionally builds the ground for the ETF hype. - I'm not saying that this isn't working. It is just the only reliable product we have to invest in stock markets with sustainable return. - If you think about how ETFs work, you will quickly understand that one ETF build a large selection of stocks. In statistical terms: You widen your sample to get less bias, but you also get lower variance.

What AI practitioners try to do, and deeply believe is: It could be that a human is not able to beat the market by picking stocks, but a computer, which is a excellent machine for pattern recognition - would be able to do it; be able to pick a sample what represents the winners in every market situation.

For deeper diving in to this topic you can read the Article by Hsu et al. (2016). They did research about if and how this could be possible.

The beautifully that Deep Reinforcement Learning brings us is, that it learns itself to recognize the patterns hidden in the data, extract the features and learn how to take the actions. It is forecasting and action taking in one step. For a deeper understanding of these algorithms and underlaying theory I would recommend you to read the book by Sutton and Barto (2018). It is like the bible in (Deep) RL.

Additionally you should watch the [Deep RL course by David Silver](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqYmG7hTraZBiG_XpjnPrSNw-1XQaM_gB) and the [updated one by other researchers of DeepMind](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqYmG7hTraZBKeNJ-JE_eyJHZ7XgBoAyb).

A good starting point to understand DRL for trading with code is the ICAIF 2020 paper and [Github Repo](https://github.com/AI4Finance-LLC/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-for-Automated-Stock-Trading-Ensemble-Strategy-ICAIF-2020) by Yang et al. (2020), which I relay on for my masters thesis.

#### References

Fama, E. (1970). Efficient Capital Markets: A Review of Theory and Empirical Work. The Journal of Finance, 25(2), 383-417. doi:10.2307/2325486

Hsu, Ming-Wei; Lessmann, Stefan; Sung, Ming-Chien; Ma, Tiejun; Johnson, Johnnie E. V. (2016): Bridging the divide in financial market forecasting: machine learners vs. financial economists. In: Expert Systems with Applications 61, pp. 215-234.

Sutton, Richard S.; Barto, Andrew (2018): Reinforcement learning. An introduction. Second edition. Cambridge, MA, London: The MIT Press (Adaptive computation and machine learning).

Yang, Hongyang and Liu, Xiao-Yang and Zhong, Shan and Walid, Anwar, Deep Reinforcement Learning for Automated Stock Trading: An Ensemble Strategy (September 11, 2020). Available at SSRN: https://ssrn.com/abstract=3690996 or http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.3690996

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called, "Episodic Learning".

Look for Monte Carlo and/or TD Lambda methods.

Opinion:
Trying to train an RL agent to actually profit and not break your bank will be rough.
My understanding is that the market moves more based on qualitative data than quantitative.
Currently, there are no models that understand the context of what is being discussed enough to accurately use to feed rewards. GPT-3 has high hopes for many people though I'm skeptical.

It's quite naive to think one can just jump in RL to apply to a research problem with no prior experience. I recommend attempting CartPole then LunarLander with the ALE (Atari Learning Environment) while learning the fundamentals via Sutton (book) and/or watching David Silver lectures.